# Observability in a dynamical system with no output

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, dynamical-systems, control-theory, linear-control

Consider the a system which is a combination of two systems connected in series, $S_2$ and $S_1$, as shown in the dynamic diagram below:

[image]

You will notice that there is no output - that is, the output of $S_1$ feeds into $S_2$

By definition, a system is observable if the rank of its observability matrix $\textbf{O}$ equals the number of system variables, $n$, where the observability matrix is:

$\begin{align}
    \textbf{O} &= \begin{bmatrix}
           \textbf{C} \\
           \textbf{CA} \\
           \textbf{CA^2}\\
           \vdots \\
           \textbf{ CA}^{n-1} 
         \end{bmatrix}
  \end{align}$

and where in turn, $C$ is the co-efficient matrix of $x(t)$ contained in the output $\textbf{y}(k) = \textbf{Cx}(t) + \textbf{Du}(t)$.

Am I correct in saying that in the example given above, the value of $\textbf{y}(t)$ is zero, therefore the value of $\textbf{C}$ is zero, therefore the rank of $\textbf{O}$ is less than $n$, and therefore the system is not observable?

Comment: If you don't have output, you don't have any information about the system, so system state recovery is not possible.

Comment: You say "you will notice that there is no output". I don't think the image tells this. From just looking at the image, I would expect that the output of $S_1$ is the output of the overall closed loop system. But without further information its not possible to give a definite answer. At the end it depends on how you define it (and the definition usually depends on your actual system). If you really define your output of the closed loop system to be $y = C x + Du$ with $C = 0, D = 0$, then as @AVK said, it is not observable. But that would be strange system (with no measurements at all).